# choose randomly one from a table with the same id

Tags: postgresql

using `postgresql v8.2`

For example I have such a table:

```
 id  | va
-----+-----
 123 | 234
 123 | 234
 123 | 456
 234 | 123
 234 | 345
 456 | 678
(6 rows)
```

what I want is to query from the table to get randomly anyone with the same `ID`

it may like:

```
 id  | va
-----+-----
 123 | 234
 234 | 123
 456 | 678
(3 rows)
```

or like:

```
 id  | va
-----+-----
 123 | 456
 234 | 345
 456 | 678
(3 rows)
```

which value doesn't matter, but there have to be one.
Thanks for proposing me any methods.

Comment: You should plan to a supported and maintained version **now** (e.g. 9.5). 8.2 is long dead and forgotten

Comment: by the way, I am using `Greenplum`, which is based on `postgresql v8.2`, and this is a legacy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select id, max(va) from table group by id;`

As you state that value of `va` doesn't matter. You could select any aggregate.

You can also use `distinct on`

`select distinct on (id) id, va from table order by id, random();`

Comment: can you explain me what the `random()` here be used for? I usually used it for generating double precision values. thanks

Comment: Yes, `random()` generates a double precision value. Here, think of it as an extra column filled with random double values which are sorted on the extra column. The advantage of using `distinct on` is that the `va` field is random and not necessarily a `max`, `min`, etc.

Comment: ah, ok, an extra column can be used to sort the query result, and here you chose random value. this enable the random choice of the value. I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `GROUP BY` ? It will just select one row for each Id in your table.

[Postgresql group by](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_group_by.htm)

> The PostgreSQL GROUP BY clause is used in collaboration with the
>   SELECT statement to group together those rows in a table that have
>   identical data.

Is your case you could have the following query :

```
SELECT id, max(va) FROM tablename GROUP BY id ;
```

Comment: Why that ? Is this better with the modification I just made ?

Comment: Thanks, it works. =)

Comment: the last one which you added doesn't work in `postgresql`. this one works